# not able to read parameters in Magento 2.2.6

Tags: error, magento2.2.6

How to read 'aref' parameter while creating new Magento account using :

http://mydomain.in/customer/account/create/?aref=88987990

I have implemented as below:

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

    /**
     * This is the method that fires when 'customer_register_success' event runs.
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute( Observer $observer ) {
    // Write to default log file: var/log/system.log
        $this->_logger->info('printing inside RegisterSuccess execute');

    $postData = $this->_request->getPostValue();
    $this->_logger->info('reached 1');
    if($postData) {
        $this->_logger->info('got $postData!!!');
    }

    $allParams = $this->_request->getParams();
    $this->_logger->info('reached 2');
    if($allParams) {
        $this->_logger->info('got $allParams!!!');
        $this->_logger->log(100,print_r($allParams,true));
    }

    $aref = $this->_request->getParam('aref', false);
    $this->_logger->info('reached 3');
    if($aref) {
        $this->_logger->info('got referrer!!!');
    }
    $this->_logger->info('reached 4');
}
```

Now when I am creating the new account with
http://mydomain.in/customer/account/create/?aref=88987990

it's giving logs below:

> [2018-11-26 05:02:27] main.INFO: printing inside RegisterSuccess
>   execute [] []
>
> [2018-11-26 05:02:27] main.INFO: reached 1 [] []
>
> [2018-11-26 05:02:27] main.INFO: got $postData!!! [] []
>
> [2018-11-26 05:02:27] main.INFO: reached 2 [] []
>
> [2018-11-26 05:02:27] main.INFO: got $allParams!!! [] []
>
> [2018-11-26 05:02:27] main.INFO: reached 3 [] []
>
> [2018-11-26 05:02:27] main.INFO: reached 4 [] []

but it's not giving 'aref' value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try to get like

```
$aref = $this->_request->getParam('aref');
```

OR

```
 $aref = $this->getRequest()->getParam('aref');
```

Comment: tried as you said but no result. any further solution?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface::getParams().
```

for example below code

```
<?php namespace Custom\Checkout\Observer; 

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface; 
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class UpdateItemBefore implements ObserverInterface 
{ 
    /** * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface */ 
    protected $_request; 
    /** * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request */ 

    public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request ) {
        $this->_request = $request; 
    } 
    /** * @param EventObserver $observer * @return void */ 
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer) 
    { 
        $reqeustParams = $this->_request->getParams(); 
    }
}
```

Hope this help you.